# Ícone dentro de atributo data-text HTML

Tags: html, html5, css3

a dúvida pode ser boba porém eu realmente não sei como fazer.
É possível escapar um ícone do awesomefonts(já tenho instalado no projeto) dentro de um atributo HTML, no caso o data-text?

Segue CSS/HTML, grato a todos!

```css
.primary-bg{
    width: 237px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    /* Secondary color */
    background-color: rgb(27, 99, 245);
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn
{
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px
}
.btn1 {

    color: rgba(255,255,255);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Primary color */
    background-color: rgb(29, 85, 148);
}
.btn1 a{
    color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.btn1 span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.btn1:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    width: 100%;
}
.btn1:hover > span{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,40px);
    transform: translate(0px,40px);
}
.btn1::after{
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;   
}
.btn1:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-bg">
  <div class="btn btn1" data-text="Icone+TextoAqui"><span>Ícone após o hover</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, basta fazer o seguinte:

Define a propriedade fonte:

```
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
```

No atributo coloque na frente do texto o código unicode referente ao ícone.

```
data-text="&#xf0e0 Icone+TextoAqui"
```

Lista completa na página [Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet), lembrando que o código é precedido de `&#x`.

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css");


.primary-bg{
    width: 237px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    /* Secondary color */
    background-color: rgb(27, 99, 245);
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn
{
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px
}
.btn1 {

    color: rgba(255,255,255);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Primary color */
    background-color: rgb(29, 85, 148);
}
.btn1 a{
    color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.btn1 span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.btn1:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    width: 100%;
}
.btn1:hover > span{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,40px);
    transform: translate(0px,40px);
}
.btn1::after{
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;   
}
.btn1:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.btn1 {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-bg">
    <div class="btn btn1" data-text="&#xf0e0 Icone+TextoAqui"><span>Ícone após o hover</span></div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT

Para aumentar a fonte somente do ícone

Define as propriedade:

```
.btn1::after {
    /* Defina a margin para separar o icon do texto */
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.btn1:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Crie atributo data com o código unicode referente ao ícone.

```
data-icon="&#xf0e0"
```

#### Exemplo

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css");


.primary-bg{
    width: 237px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    /* Secondary color */
    background-color: rgb(27, 99, 245);
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn
{
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px
}
.btn1 {

    color: rgba(255,255,255);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Primary color */
    background-color: rgb(29, 85, 148);
}
.btn1 a{
    color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.btn1 span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.btn1:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    width: 100%;
}
.btn1:hover > span{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,40px);
    transform: translate(0px,40px);
}
.btn1::after{
    /* Defina a margin para separar o icon do texto */
    margin-left: 20px;
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    transform: translate(-30%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn1:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.btn1:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-bg">
    <div class="btn btn1" data-icon="&#xf0e0" data-text="Icone+TextoAqui"><span>Ícone após o hover</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou para mim, porém somente quando utilizo o cdn que colocou no inicio do css. Quando coloco as tags ***<i class="fas fa-search"></i>*** recebo o ícone normalmente. Poderia me dizer o que ocorre?

Comment: Quando coloco as tags ***<i class="fas fa-search"></i>*** em qualquer lugar da minha página eu recebo o ícone, o que quer dizer que estou a importar corretamente o arquivo de fontes do awesome com as tags ***<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">***

Comment: Funciona! O que não funciona é o unicode(***&#xf002***) quando retiro o cdn.

Comment: Estou a utilizar a 5.0 mas acredito não ser esse o problema pois baixei e importei essa que você utilizou e o problema continua. Seria por que estou a utilizar em localhost? Utilizo o laragon como servidor para os projetos.

Comment: O problema está na versão 5, não aceita o unicode. Baixei a 4.7 do site com as pastas css/fonts e funcionou perfeitamente. Fiquei sem entender a razão de não funcionar unicode com a 5, vou dar uma olhada no release depois. Agradeço a força. God Bless!

Comment: Não querendo pedir muito mas já pedindo, você saberia como dar um font-size nesse unicode? Com pseudo elemento eu consigo mas este está dentro de um attr no caso.

Comment: Sim, já fiz isso, porém o que quero é aumentar somente o ícone.

Comment: Resolveu para mim, muito obrigado. God Bless!